# How to get dataframe into c(ID = c(lat_val,lon_val)) format?

Tags: r

How can I get my dataframe into c(ID = c(lat_val,lon_val)) format?

```
coords[,c(1,3,4)]
# A tibble: 224 x 3
   SITE    LAT  LONG
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 pt01  39.6 -97.7
 2 pt02  39.6 -98.7
 3 pt03  38.8 -99.1
 4 pt04  37.7 -97.8
```

I want to add the desired output to this function:

```
stencil <- simplegeom(data.frame(
                  'point1' = c(-89, 46), 
                  'point2' = c(-88.6, 45.2)))
```

Desired output below:

```
data.frame('pt1' = c(-89, 46), 'pt2' = c(-88.6, 45.2), 'pt3' = c(-xx, yy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
coords <- read.table(text = "   SITE    LAT  LONG
                     1 pt01  39.6 -97.7
                     2 pt02  39.6 -98.7
                     3 pt03  38.8 -99.1
                     4 pt04  37.7 -97.8", header = TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(t(coords[, -1]))
colnames(df) <- paste0("pt", colnames(df))
df # output
       pt1   pt2   pt3   pt4
LAT   39.6  39.6  38.8  37.7
LONG -97.7 -98.7 -99.1 -97.8

# now use simplegeom() on df
library(geoknife)
stencil <- simplegeom(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I only want the desired output to be that text, not the dataframe itself.

Comment: Didn't get you right, sorry. Which data do you want to transform to get your desired output?

Comment: no worries! I want to transform the data in the table provided to be 'pt1' = c(-89, 46), 'pt2' = c(-88.6, 45.2) etc...

Comment: if that different from `df$pt1`, `df$pt2`, etc.?

Comment: I guess I should specify that I have a few thousand points to do this to. I want to input them all into that function but need it entered exactly like that. I just can't do them all manually lol

Comment: In your example function `simplegeom()` uses a data.frame as argument, right? If so using `simplegeom(df)` should be ok, no?

Comment: I thought so too. But I get this error. Does it need to be an sf object? Error in asMethod(object) : 
  data.frame input to simplegeom needs to be have 2 rows: longitude & latitude

Comment: Ah sorry, `df` is not a data.frame yet, I will edit my answer